# Symfony2 MongoDB QueryBuilder select values with condition

Tags: mongodb, symfony, query-builder

I'm using symfony2 with the doctrine mongodb bundle, and I need to use the QueryBuilder to select different values form a list using a condition. The issue is that its not using the condition to return the values.
My code inside the repository it's something like this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
     ->distinct('embedded_document1_list.another_embedded_document.field2')
     ->field('embedded_document1_list.another_embedded_document.field1')
     ->equals("some_string");
```

This code is returning every different value of embedded_document1_list.another_embedded_document.field2, even if the field1 is different from "some_string".

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the condition (equals) on the field and not on the query, try something like that:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
 ->distinct('embedded_document1_list.another_embedded_document.field2')
 ->field('embedded_document1_list.another_embedded_document.field1')->equals("some_string")
 ->execute();
```